# the requested resource is not available tomcat intellij idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, tomcat

Всем привет. Пишу веб приложение на Intellij Idea Ultimate(jsf приложение), когда запускаю Tomcat выдает ошибку 
the requested resource is not available 
Все настроила и ошибок в консоли нету. помогите please уже второй день бьюсь над этим вопросом.
web.xml сгенерировал автоматически

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

вот index.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
   <f:view>
      <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
   </f:view>
</html>
```

ничего сама не добавляла, может проблема в артефактах, не знаю((
[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: Очень мало данных для ответа.Попробуйте расширить вопрос. Добавьте mapping web.xml и адрес запроса как минимум...Если используете аннотации то примеры классов

Comment: Какой url вызываете?

Comment: @SergeyMitrofanov localhost:8080/название проекта

Comment: Попробуйте в конфиг добавить секцию '<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По умолчанию для Tomcat действует

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Ваш `index.xhtml` в этот список не входит. Но вы можете проверить что но есть явно указав его имя в запросе

localhost:8080/название проекта/index.xhtml

Что бы работало "по умолчанию", нужно добавить `welcome-file-list/welcome-file=index.xhtml` в **web.xml**

Comment: спасибо вам большое заработал